# GKS QtTerm window not responding when plotting with Julia

Tags: plot, julia, juno-ide

Here's my code:

```
using Plots
using Interact

function golfBall(xPos, gravity, angleInRadians, initialVelocity)
    num = -(xPos * xPos * gravity)
    cosTheta = cos(angleInRadians)
    den = 2 * initialVelocity * initialVelocity * cosTheta * cosTheta
    term1 = num/den
    term2 = xPos * tan(angleInRadians)
    return term1 + term2
end

@manipulate for theta=0:0.01:pi/2, g = 10, u = 25
    f(x) = golfBall(x, g, theta, u)
    gr(show = true)
    plt = plot(f, 0, 100)
    display(plt)
end
```

It works well in Juno's plots pane. Outside Juno, a GKS QtTerm window is created but cannot be opened, or switched to. It's not the `@manipulate` macro, even `plot(rand(5), rand(5))` doesnt work in REPL

Edit: It works now, and the graph is displayed but no sliders or textboxes.

Comment: Which platform are you on?